# Mathematical induction can I assume this?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ so that $a+b\in\mathbb Q$ and $ab\in\mathbb Q$ prove that $a^n+b^n\in\mathbb Q$.

So I tried to prove using mathematical induction and got to:

$$(a^k+b^k)(a+b)-ab(a^{k-1}+b^{k-1})$$

Now we know that $(a^k+b^k)(a+b)\in\mathbb Q$ from the Induction assumption.

My question is that if I assume something is true for all $n=k$ does it  mean it's also true for $k-1$? 
and why?

Comment: You might find this guide helpful when posting a question- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference !

Comment: Search strong induction.

Comment: Any way, you can replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with any subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a perfectly valid proof by induction that assumes the statement is true for $k$ and $k-1$ and deduces that it is true for $k+1$. However, in order to do this you need to check **two** base cases (i.e. that it works for $n=1$ and $n=2$) rather than one. This is because the first case that isn't a base case has to depend on two previous cases, which both have to be base cases.

This works because once you know it's true for $1$ and $2$ you can show it's true for $3$; you already know $2$ so it's true for $2$ and $3$, which allows you to show it for $4$; and so on...

This is something you often see in e.g. proving things about the Fibonacci numbers, where each one is defined in terms of the previous two.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assume that.

Suppose you have your predicate $P(n)$ to prove and consider the predicate $Q(n): \forall j\le n: P(j)$. Of course we see that $Q(n)\Rightarrow P(n)$ so if we prove that $Q(n)$ is true for all natural number then so is $P(n)$

Now if you can prove that $Q(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$ you use the fact that $Q(n)\land P(n+1)\Rightarrow Q(n+1)$ So that means that we know that $Q(n)\Rightarrow Q(n+1)$.

So given that $Q(0)$ is true and $Q(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$ then we have that $Q(n)$ is true for all natural numbers and therefore also $P(n)$.

Note that your assumption is slightly different however. If you have the predicate $R(n): P(n) \land P(n-1)$ that doesn't make sense if $n<1$, but otherwise we have that $Q(n)\Rightarrow R(n)$. You would to use this need to dafine $R(0)$ specially or prove $P(1)$ explicitely.